# Select2 doesn't show options

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-select2

I'm currently testing Select2.js in my ASP.NET MVC project.

The first test on a "normal" view just worked fine but now I'm trying to add this to a select box inside a partial view that gets loaded on Ajax Call and then displayed inside a `<div>` on the normal view page.

The code to generate the dropdown looks like this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("addRole",
   new SelectList(ViewBag.availableRoles, "Id", "Name"),
   "Rolle auswählen", 
   new { @name="addRole", @class = "form-control" }
)
```

And on the end of the partial view file I added the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //var data = [{ id: 1, text: "Test" }];

    $("#addRole").select2({
        //data: data
    });
});
```

It looks like it works because of the look of the select box changes but when I try to open it, it just shows nothing. Same happens when I uncomment the `data` variable code above.

It just doesn't show anything to me and I don't know why.

I've already tried to add the JavaScript code to `$(document).ajaxComplete` or in the `success` function from the AJAX call but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Did you check if `ViewBag.availableRoles` contains valid values with fields `Id` and `Name`?

Comment: That has nothing to do with `select2` since it's not working without it too...

Comment: Yes, when I look into the DOM elements I see all entries. Also when I remove the `$("#addRole").select2()` it works fine.

Comment: to whom it might interest (such as [@atish-shakya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7621800/atish-shakya)), and completely off topic, this is the reason of so many edits: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/48255477#48255477

Answer (score 9):

I got the answer now.
The problem was not that the select2 element has no items, the problem was the given items did not show up. So I thought about why didn´t they show up and found out that I´m really stupid. 
It did show up, but I can´t see it because of the z-index. My popup window got a z-index of 20k so the dropdown list was behind the window.

So to solve this just add:

```
.select2-dropdown {
    z-index:99999;
}
```

Or add a dropdownCssClass to the select2 settings with the given z-index like this:

```
.select2-dropdown.increasezindex {
    z-index:99999;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#addRole").select2({
        dropdownCssClass:'increasezindex'
    });
});
```

Comment: glad you worked it out my mate

Answer (score 7):

In my case, I was displaying a select2 on a pop-up element and this causes the dropdown to disappear because it is attached by default to the `<body>` element.

Select2 [troubleshooting](https://select2.org/troubleshooting/common-problems#select2-does-not-function-properly-when-i-use-it-inside-a-bootst) guide highlights a similar issue with Bootstrap modals.

To overcome this problem I had to use the [dropdown placement option](https://select2.org/dropdown#dropdown-placement) provided,

```
let $select = $('select'), 
  $parent = $select.parent();

$select.select2({
  dropdownParent: $parent
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution here: [Select2 does not function properly when I use it inside a Bootstrap modal](https://web.archive.org/web/20230923101440/https://select2.org/troubleshooting/common-problems#select2-does-not-function-properly-when-i-use-it-inside-a-bootst)

It says:

> This will cause the dropdown to be attached to the modal, rather than
> the `<body>` (here modal is the element)